# assign a new property (a) to json object and give it a value of another property (b), then I want to change the (b) and keep (a) does not work

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {
 a: 1,
 b:2,
 c:3
} 
const first = obj.a;
obj.z = first;
obj.a = '';
```

when I apply obj.a = ''; I get the result

```
const obj = {
 a: '',
 b:2,
 c:3,
 z:'',
}
```

it causes obj.z to change too but I need to keep the original value of z --> 1;

Comment: This code in not valid. Variables cannot start with a number.

Comment: yes I just made up to not copy the the original object, fixed*

Comment: That's due to you storing a [reference rather than a copy](https://javascript.info/object-copy).

Comment: Please create a [mre] - your code does not do what you're saying it does

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Js uses assign by reference in default so you need to using assign by value you can reach that by `Object.assign()`, Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) illustrate the mentioned method.

Try this:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b:2,
  c:3
} 
const first = obj.a;
Object.assign(obj, {z: first});
obj.a = '';
```

Comment: thank you, for some reason, it updates 'z' as well :( I'm really frustrated about this